# how to read image file as data url using php

Tags: php

In javascript, I read the file data by binding the on-change method to the file input and saving the file data into another input using the following code

```
$("#release_cover_custom").on('change', function (evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

        // Only process image files.
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }

        var reader = new FileReader();

        // Closure to capture the file information.
        reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
            return function (e) {
                $("#release_cover_custom_data").val(e.target.result);
            };
        })(f);

        // Read in the image file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }


});
```

why i use the above code?, to store the image data, because i have a form where i provide settings for the email template that would be sent later and there i have to provide the background image to be used inside the email, i need to preview the email with all the settings and along with the background image provided to upload before saving the form or uploading the image, so i read the image data, save it to an input and then open a modal window to preview email and post all the necessary variables there including the image data which is then used in the following way inside the css to apply the background-image like below in my php view file

`background-image:url('" . $background_image . "') !important;`

Now i want to do the achieve the same thing via php, means if i have the image saved to a path and i want to read the image data and use it in the same way i did using javascript to futher pass it to the css property,

i tried to use `base64_encode(file_get_contents('path/to/file'))`

but the encoding seems to be different for the image data, as the background image is not shown should i be using some other method to achieve it in php.

Comment: It seems you want to display selected image before user upload it.. am i right ?   
are you able to create a fiddle for the same  ?

Comment: no i have displayed the image already before uploading it , after saving the image i want to read the image data in the same way i did in javascript and load it in the background , i know it would be confusing that if i already have the image then why dont i use the url instead , i have to add more checks in the existing code for the preview and i thought if i could do the same process via php then all i need to do is to pass the image data and it will be loaded. hope i was able to explain the problem

Comment: The data url has to look like `data:[<media type>][;base64],<data>`. You can't just use the base64 encoded data as the background image url.

Comment: Hmm , that is something i didnt knew before, so my previous code was like below


`$image_data=base64_decode(file_get_contents('/path/to/file'))`



and by my understanding i changed it to below 

`$finfo  =   finfo_open('fileinfo_mime_type');
        $mime_type  =   finfo_file('/path/to/file');
$background_image = 'data:[<'.$mime_type.'>][;'.base64_encode(file_get_contents('/path/to/image')).']<data>';`

am i doing it the right way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@quagaar reply (on the question) helped me solve the problem and replaced the following

```
$background_image=base64_encode(file_get_contents('/path/to/file'));
```

with

```
$background_image='data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents('/path/to/file'));
```

and everything works fine as expected.

**EDIT**:

between i was dealing with images only and if you are working with Images only and you need mime type (e.g. for headers, or like my case), then this is a fast and reliable technique:

```
$file = 'path/to/image.jpg';
$image_mime = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($file));
```

It will output true image mime type even if you rename your image file.